# `forever` Combinator with Higher Kinded Type

Tags: scala

I'm trying to run the following combinator from [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/):

```
trait AddlCombinators[F[_]] extends Monad[F[_]] {
  def forever[A, B](a: F[A]): F[B] = {
    lazy val t: F[B] = forever(a)
    a flatMap (_ => t)
  }
}
```

But it's not compiling:

```
[error] AddlCombinators.scala:7: value flatMap is not a member of type 
      parameter F[A]
[error]     a flatMap (_ => t)
[error]       ^
```

My understanding is that I need to use `F[_]` as it denotes a higher kinded type.

For example, I had written a `Monad[List]` in a past chapter of this book:

```
object ListMonad extends Monad[List] {
  def unit[A](a: => A): List[A] = List(a)

  def flatMap[A,B](ma: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] =
    ma.map(x => f(x)).flatten
}
```

**EDIT** Adding `Monad` and `Functor` code

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def map[A,B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}

trait Monad[F[_]] extends Functor[F] {
    def unit[A](a: => A): F[A]
    def flatMap[A,B](ma: F[A])(f: A => F[B]): F[B]
```

How can I resolve the above compile-time error? Also, what is the meaning of `F[_]` as the type to `AddlCombinators` and `Monad`? Can a general "higher kinded type" be used?

Comment: I would suggest that you include the definition of `Monad`. It is generally better to post self-contained code snippets (especially given that not everybody owns a copy of "Functional Programming in Scala"). Not only that, but I would have expected `Monad` to be defined as `trait Monad[F[_]] { ... }`, but this is not consistent with your definition of `trait AddlCombinators[F[_]] extends Monad[F[_]]`

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles - thank you for that suggestion. I edited to include `Monad` and `Functor`.

Comment: Mmm, so I was right, your definition of `AddlCombinators` is wrong, it should be `AddlCombinators[F[_]] extends Monad[F]`. Also, Jamil is right, you can fix your code by doing `flatMap( a ) (_ => t)` instead of `a flatMap (_ => t)`. Though some libraries might add syntactic sugar to allow this notation (notably scalaz, see https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz#syntax), where `a flatMap (_ => t)` will basically just forward to `flatMap( a ) (_ => t)`, so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a flatMap (_ => t)` is the culprit here.

As per the code given, you can use `flatMap(a)(_ => t)` to get it compiling.

Monad interface does not automatically add monadic operators to any parameterised type unless you use implicits.

`F[_]` is an existential type which means that F is a type which contains some other type, equivalent to: `trait F {type A}`. Every Monad is a Functor, and only parameterised types can be Functors, which is why you need to parameterize Monads with `F[_]`. Put another way, only paratmeterized types can satisfy Monad/Functor interface. A type parameterized by a parameterized type  `(* -> *) -> *` is a higher kinded type. `F[_]` is the least restrictive, hence most general type that can be used here. Other paramterized types can be made to look like F[_] via type projections. For example, to define a Monad for a right biased Either type, you can use `type FA = ({type l[a] = Either[L, a]})#l` as `F[_]`. See [here](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/Either.scala#L66) for complete code for Monad for Either.